# make nextjs 13 to save styles as css file using Mui

Tags: reactjs, optimization, next.js, material-ui, next.js13

I wrote an nextjs (13) project and use Mui(v5). and use mui theme and styled and wrote sx attribute.

After build project in server rendered html all od style is on head of page and between  and no one is not in link tag as external css file.
i use https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-ui-nextjs-ts but it was usefull to concat all style in one style. and not for file css.